# cuda, OpenGL interoperability: cudaErrorMemoryAllocation error on cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda

I am having random cuda memory allocation error on use of `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer()`. I have a fairly large OpenGL PBO object which is shared with it and CUDA. The PBO object is created as follows:

```
GLuint          buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(target, rows * cols * 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
glUnmapBuffer(_target);
glBindBuffer(_target, 0);
```

The object is quite large. width and height are 5000. However, it allocates fine on my GPU. Now, I am sharing this between OpenGL and CUDA as follows. I have a simple class to manage the it as follows:

```
class CudaPBOGraphicsResource
{
public:
    CudaPBOGraphicsResource(GLuint pbo_id);
    ~CudaPBOGraphicsResource();
     inline cudaGraphicsResource_t resource() const { return _cgr; }
private:
    cudaGraphicsResource_t          _cgr;
};

CudaPBOGraphicsResource::CudaPBOGraphicsResource(GLuint pbo_id)
{
    checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&_cgr, pbo_id,
                    cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsNone));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &_cgr, 0));
}

CudaPBOGraphicsResource::~CudaPBOGraphicsResource()
{
    if (_cgr) {
        checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &_cgr, 0));
    }
}
```

Now I do the OpenGL and CUDA interoperability as follows:

```
{
    CudaPBOGraphicsResource input_cpgr(pbo_id);
    uchar4 * input_ptr = 0;
    size_t num_bytes;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void 
                    **)&input_ptr, &num_bytes,
                    input_cpgr.resource()));

    call_my_kernel(input_ptr);
}
```

This runs for my inputs for a while but after sometime it crashes with:

```
CUDA error code=2(cudaErrorMemoryAllocation) 
                 "cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&_cgr, pbo_id, 
                  cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsNone)" 
Segmentation fault
```

I am not sure why there is memory allocation going on as I thought this was shared. I added `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after the kernel call but the error still persists. My `call_my_kernel()` function is now pretty much doing nothing, so there are no other CUDA calls that can raise this error!

I am using Cuda 7 on linux with a K4000 Quadro card.

**EDIT**
I updated the driver to the latest 346.72 version and the error still happens. It also does not depend on the kernel call. Just calling `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer()` seems to leak memory on the GPU. Running nvidia-smi as the program is running shows the memory going up steadily. I am still at a loss as to why there is any copying happening...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer to my conundrum and I hope it will help anyone else using CUDA-OGL together.

The problem was that I was calling:

```
checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&_cgr, pbo_id,
                cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsNone));
```

everytime. This actually needs to be called only once and then I just need to call map/unmap on the _cgr object.